# How do I include the reason for the crash in crash logs?

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, assertion, crash-log

When my app crashes when connected to Xcode, I get all the information I need to debug and fix the problem. But not when the app crashes when not connected to Xcode, **I don't know if was a nil unwrap, an assertion failure or an exception.**

In the latter two cases, the assertion or exception message is also missing.

How do I get Xcode to include this information in the crash logs?

I have "Strip debug symbols during copy" and "Strip linked product" set to NO, and the Debug Information Format for Debug builds is set to DWARF with dSYM. And yes, I'm installing debug builds on my phone. I get a symbolicated stack trace, but not the above information.

---

**Case 1: Unwrap nil**: The line "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" is missing in the crash log.

**Case 2: Assertion failure**: If I have:

```
assert(level > 2, "Level should've been at least 2")
```

"Level should've been at least 2" doesn't show up in the crash log. Sometimes, it doesn't even say that it crashed due to an assertion failure (as opposed to some other reason).

**Case 3: Exception**: The exception message like the following is missing:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '*** -[AVCaptureDevice setTorchMode:] May not be called
>   without first successfully gaining exclusive ownership of the device
>   using -lockForConfiguration:'

Sometimes, it doesn't even say that it crashed due to an exception (as opposed to some other reason).

How do I get crashes when not connected to Xcode to have all the information I get with crashes when connected to Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is to use an analytics tool. Have a look at [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/)

Comment: That's one option, but for now I'm not looking at logging in production, but during testing.

Comment: You can log during testing as well and take it out of production if you don't want it there.

Comment: I know, but the question is where there's something simpler if I just want it to work only on my own phone. If it crashes, the next time I connect it to Xcode, it should give me the info mentioned in the question.

Comment: I haven't come across anything that does what you are asking. I would have gone with using dSYMs and crash logs but since that doesn't solve your problem, I'm out of ideas. Maybe someone else might be able to help you out in this regard. Good luck

Comment: Do crash reporters report the information I mentioned in my question? If so, if nothing else works out, I'll use them. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the crash. Some do, some don't